# Hi everyone. i have a silly problem in a code. you can help me?

Tags: javascript

*it's my first time here, I still have to settle down. the problem with the code is that the result does not come out. Help*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>


    <form>
    <h2>Calacola l'area del quadrto</h2>

    valore 1: <input type="text" id="fa">

    valore 2: <input type="text" id="ca"> 

    <div id="operatore" value="moltiplicazione"></div>
    <br>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="calcola()" value="invio">risultato = </button>
   
    <!--  <input type="button" id="risultato" onclick="calcola()" value="invio">   --> 
    
   <div id="risultato"></div>

   </form>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
       

        function calcola() {
            var a = parseInt(document.querySelector('#fa').value);
            var b = parseInt(document.querySelector('#ca').value);
            var op = document.querySelector('#operatore').value;
            var calcolo;
            

            if (op == "moltiplicazione") {
                calcolo = a*b;
            }

        document.querySelector('#risultato').innerHTML=calcolo;
        
        }
    

    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

*I don't understand what it could be, it all seems right, it doesn't give me debugging error  I hope you help me*

Comment: You have your markup in the `<head>` instead of in the `<body>`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "result doesn't come out"? Which result? What do you expect and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already mentioned, you messed a few things up.
First of all you have to put your form/markup into the body. Secondly a div cannot have a value, so may you use a hidden input or some kind of select.

Here is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/j2gesdbm/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <h2>Calacola l'area del quadrto</h2>

    valore 1: <input type="text" id="fa">

    valore 2: <input type="text" id="ca"> 

    <input type="hidden" id="operatore" value="moltiplicazione"/>
    <br>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="calcola()" value="invio">risultato = </button>
   
    <!--  <input type="button" id="risultato" onclick="calcola()" value="invio">   --> 
    
   <div id="risultato"></div>

   </form>
    <script>
       

        function calcola() {
            var a = parseInt(document.querySelector('#fa').value);
            var b = parseInt(document.querySelector('#ca').value);
            var op = document.querySelector('#operatore').value;
            var calcolo;
            

            if (op == "moltiplicazione") {
                calcolo = a*b;
            }

        document.querySelector('#risultato').innerHTML=calcolo;
        
        }
    

    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a "value" attribute for a div

```
<div id="operatore" value="moltiplicazione"></div>
```

You can not add the "value" attribute to a div. If you want give a value to this tag, you have to change to an input tag

```
<input id="operatore" value="moltiplicazione"></input>
```

If you don't want the input tag to be visible you can set the input type as "hidden"

```
<input type="hidden" id="operatore" value="moltiplicazione"></input>
```

I hope I've helped :)